# link to a page and display a specific tab contents

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick

I do not know Javascript very well, and I'm working with some sample javascript tab code that I pulled off the Internet. I have a page (Travel) with many tabs (years). Each tab opens different content (links to photo galleries) in the same page. When clicked, each gallery opens in a new page. On that new page, I want to link back to the Travel page and display the content of a specific tab (the same year the user is viewing).

I'm using Bootstrap 4.5.0
Running on localhost (Win10)

Code from Travel page

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onClick="openYear(event, 'A few words')" id="defaultOpen">A few words</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onClick="openYear(event, '2002')">2002</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onClick="openYear(event, '2003')">2003</button>
</div>

<div id="2002" class="tabcontent">

    <h2>2002</h2>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 mb-4">
        <a href="travel-vienna02.html">Vienna, Austria<img class="img-fluid" src="images/travel/2002-vienna/vienna-9.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href="travel-vienna02.html"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 mb-4">
        <a href="travel-sicily1.html">Sicily (Savoca)<img class="img-fluid" src="images/travel/2002-sicily1/savoca17.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href="travel-sicily1.html"></a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 mb-4">
       <a href="travel-sicily2.html">Sicily (Cefalu)<img class="img-fluid" src="images/travel/2002-sicily2/cefalu01.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href="travel-sicily2.html"></a>
      </div>
</div><!-- /tab 2002-->

    <script>
    function openYear(evt, year) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(year).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>
```

On the "Travel" page if I select the second tab ("2002"), the page displays a series of links. Clicking on one of these links opens a new page - "Sicily1.html. On this page I want to create a link and point back to "travel.html" and when loaded, have that page display content from the tab "2002", not the default tab content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a query string parameter when navigating back to "travel.html":

```
<form action="travel.html?year=insert_year">
    <input type="submit" value="Go Back" />
</form>
```

And on the "travel.html" you can add an event listener to the page loading and active the specific tab if present in the query string parameters:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const myParam = urlParams.get('year');
    // activate tab
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting the default tab displayed on the Travel page. I added the script to the end of the Travel page. I tried several versions of the "back" link:  <form action="travel.html?year=2002">
    <input type="submit" value="Go Back" />
</form>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="window.location='travel.html'" onload="openYear(event, '2002')">2002</button>
</div>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onload="window.location='travel.html?year=2002'">2002</button>
</div>

<a href="travel.html#2002">travel</a>

Comment: Can you provide a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your question?